# How to make a number string decrement based on the value of the number

Tags: c#

I want the the timeToString values change based on the count changing.So when the count of seconds decrement the second.Count.ToString("59") should decrement to "58".In the debug the PondoreCount function is working as expected, however I can't see the value decrementing in the console.

```
public class PonodoreTimer : Clock
    {
        private Clock _seconds;
        private Clock _minutes;

        public PonodoreTimer()
        {
            _seconds = new Clock();
            _minutes = new Clock();
            _seconds.Count = 59;
            _minutes.Count = 24;
            //   string timeToString = _minutes.Count.ToString("24") + ":" + _seconds.Count.ToString("59");
        }

      
        public string PondoreTimerInString()
        {
            string timeToString = _minutes.Count.ToString("24") + ":" + _seconds.Count.ToString("59");
            return timeToString;
        }
        
       

        public void PonodoreCount()
        {
            
            //string timeToString = _minutes.Count + ":" + _seconds.Count;

            //Console.WriteLine(timeToString);
            while (_minutes.Count != 0)
            {
               _seconds.Decrement();
                if(_seconds.Count == 0)
                {
                    _minutes.Decrement();
                    _seconds.Count = 59;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put the Writeline inside the while loop.  You have the writeline before the actual decrementing is occurring.

Comment: Use a TimeSpan..

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing can be replaced by:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(25);
var one = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

while(ts > TimeSpan.Zero){
  ts = ts - one;
  Console.WriteLine($@"{ts:mm\:ss}");
}

24:59, 24:58 ...
```

If you want it to count down from 25:00, put the WriteLine before the subtract

Answer (score 0):

Change this string

```
 string timeToString = _minutes.Count.ToString("24") + ":" + _seconds.Count.ToString("59");
```

to this

```
string timeToString = _minutes.Count.ToString() + ":" + _seconds.Count.ToString();
```

or you always get *"24"* and *"59"*...